# How do I iterate through a DataFrame column to count the number of occurrences of a substring within a string?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, count

I have a pandas dataframe of scraped tweet information. It looks a bit like this:

| created_at | full_tweet |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-20-22 | " All square in Austria. \n\n #UEL " |
| 2020-10-22 | " We're back underway in the @EuropaLeague \n\n... " |
| 2020-10-22 | " We're back underway in the @EuropaLeague \n\n... " |
| 2020-10-22 | " DAVID LEVELS IT UP! \n\n 1-1 (70) \n\n # " |

I also have a second dataframe with UTF-8 text for every emoji, which looks like:

| emoji | meaning |
| --- | --- |
| ðŸ˜„ | A_smiley1 |
| ðŸ˜ƒ | A_smiley2 |
| ðŸ˜€ | A_smiley3 |
| ðŸ˜Š | A_smiley4 |
| â˜ºï¸ | A_blush |

I am a relatively new user to Python and have no idea how to go about this, but I would like to scan each row in the tweet dataframe "full_tweet" column and count occurrences of every emoji text, resulting in a final count column. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
for ind in emojis:
count = str(clubs_df.full_tweet[ind]).count(emojis.emoji)
clubs_df['emoji_count'] = clubs_df.emoji_count[ind] + count
```

This throws a KeyError that simply lists "emoji". Would anyone have any suggestions for me to use for through this dataframe's rows?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please see [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "*Show me how to solve this coding problem*" [is off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). You have to [make an honest attempt at the solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and then ask a specific question about your implementation.

Comment: Try using [`pandas.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) or [`pandas.Series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html)

Comment: @s-ellingso, what will be the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking, but just what i see from your post and understood..

**DataFrame:**

```
print(df)
   created_at                                         full_tweet
0  2020-20-22             " All square in Austria. \n\n #UEL ".
1  2020-10-22  " We're back underway in the @EuropaLeague \n...
2  2020-10-22  " We're back undway in the @EuropaLeague \n\n...
3  2020-10-22  " DAVID LEVELS IT UP! \n\n 1-1  (70) \n\n # "
```

**Try Bleow:**

```
emoji_count = df['full_tweet'].apply(lambda x : emojis.count(str(x)))
pd.concat([df, emoji_count.apply(pd.Series)],1)
   created_at                                         full_tweet  0
0  2020-20-22             " All square in Austria. \n\n #UEL ".  1
1  2020-10-22  " We're back underway in the @EuropaLeague \n...  1
2  2020-10-22  " We're back undway in the @EuropaLeague \n\n...  1
3  2020-10-22  " DAVID LEVELS IT UP! \n\n 1-1  (70) \n\n # "  3
```

Comment: This is definitely what I'm trying to do, however when I enter this code I get a ValueError - "ValueError: No axis named All square in Austria. 

 #UEL for object type DataFrame".